# How to fix "Couldn't terminate the existing process for" in Lock Task Mode (Device Owner)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, adb, device-owner

## Problem

My `App.apk` is currently set as a custom `Launcher` and also set as a [`Device Owner`](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc) to have access to the [`Lock Task Mode`](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode?hl=en#overview).

Command to be a Device Owner

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.package.name/.MyDeviceAdminReceiver`

Previous to that I could just press `Run App` and the old `app.apk process` would have been killed and the new one would appear.

Now I have to manually reinstall it by pressing `build` and then using `adb`

- `adb install -t -r <path/app-debug.apk>`

I have already tried the [attaching to debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225662/9370018) solution provided here which doesn't work.

According to Googles Issue Tracker [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181004316#comment22) is the reason why it happens.

> It looks like we don't recognize when an app features BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission which protects them from being force-stoped.

## My goal

I don't want to manually write `adb install` I want to achieve the same fluent workflow without this workaround stuff. Pressing `Run App` should have the same effect as before.

Im pretty confident there is a custom `run configuration` that can help with this problem but this is my first android project so any ideas or help would be appreciated.

## What I have tried

I tried to setup a `before launch` shell script on the `Run/Debug configuration` but all `adb` commands are not working to stop my app.

1. > adb shell pm disable com.package.name
   >
   > > Security exception: Cannot disable a protected package: com.package.name
2. > adb uninstall com.package.name
   >
   > > Failure [DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER]

Answer (score 0):

I have created custom gradle task in run configurations which installs app on my managed device.

I used gradle task `installDebug`. You might need use other tasks but this one work perfectly for me.